# How to truncate tables during export/import in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, import, export

I'm exporting full Oracle data pumps very often. However, there are 3 tables that tend to be very big and have (for me) useless data.
I can't truncate the tables before I take the dump, but I don't want the datafiles to be bloated either. (Those tables can take up multiple GB)
For now, I am excluding those tables during export or import:

```
expdp full=y exclude=table:\"IN \(\'tONE\',\'tTWO\',\'tTHREE\')\" ...
```

But then I must recreate the tables later...
Is it possible to export and/or import the data pumps fully except those 3 tables where I want just the table definitions not the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a [data filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-CDA1477D-4710-452A-ABA5-D29A0F3E3852) for each of the tables whose data you want to exclude, with a condition that always evaluates to false:

```
query='"tONE":"where 1=0","tTWO":"where 1=0","tTHREE":"where 1=0"'
```

If you were using a parameter file you wouldn't need the single quotes:

```
query="tONE":"where 1=0","tTWO":"where 1=0","tTHREE":"where 1=0"
```

I've enclosed the table names in double quotes only because your original version did, and implies mixed-case (quoted-identifier) names; if they aren't then those can be omitted too.

As a quick demo, exporting a couple of tables from the HR schema:

```
expdp hr/hr full=N tables='countries,departments,jobs' \
  query='countries:"where 1=0",hr."DEPARTMENTS":"WHERE 1=0"'
```

the log shows:

```
. . exported "HR"."JOBS"                                 7.109 KB      19 rows
. . exported "HR"."COUNTRIES"                            5.906 KB       0 rows
. . exported "HR"."DEPARTMENTS"                          6.484 KB       0 rows
```

---

In a Windows batch file, this format worked:

```
query='countries:"where 1=0"','"DEPARTMENTS":"WHERE 1=0"'
```

... which is probably what I should have shown originally; so you need:

```
query='"tONE":"where 1=0"','"tTWO":"where 1=0"','"tTHREE":"where 1=0"'
```

Comment: `query` is great and it works on imports and exports. However I have still a little problem with querying multiple tables. If I query multiple tables it will fail to import the first table and import the others normaly throwing ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. I am on Windows so I guess `,` doesn't need to be escaped?

Comment: @T-Me - are you setting the query parameter on the command line or in a parameter file; and do you have the clauses enclosed in single quotes or not? Not sure about Windows, in Linux it liked the single quotes on the command line but not in the file; Windows might not like them on the command line either. (But then might need some other way to escape the double quotes...)

Comment: I use them in the command line (usually in an automatic generated bat) and tried a bunch of different ways to write them. enclosed in single quotes and brackets, escaped double quotes and so on.

Comment: @T-Me - finally got to somewhere I could play with this in Windows; after a bit of experimentation and thought, each table/filter is enclosed in its own single quotes. Added an example that worked, and what I think yours will look like. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it in two steps, i.e. producing two export files:

- one as you're already doing it - tables with data
- another using `content=METADATA_ONLY` `expdp` parameter